# C# Razor - error al guardar un formulario con radio button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un problema al guardar un formulario por un radio button, siempre guarda el valor cero y debe ser a demanda según lo que el usuario selecciona:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="BONUS" class="col-md-2 control-label">Bono:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">

        if (Model.BONUS== 1)
            {
            <text>
            <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="BONUS" value="@Model.BONUS">No</label>
            <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="BONUS" checked="checked" value="@Model.BONUS">Si</label>
            </text>
            }
            else if (Model.BONUS == 0)
            {
            <text>
            <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="BONUS" checked="checked" value="@Model.BONUS">No</label>
            <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="BONUS"  value="@Model.BONUS">Si</label>
            </text>
            }
            else
            {
            <text>
            <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="BONUS" value="0">No</label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="BONUS" value="1">Si</label>
            </text>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en los dos primeros casos (`Model.BONUS == 0` y `1`) el `value` de cada input es `@Model.BONUS` independientemente del "Sí" y "No" que tienes en ambos casos.

lo único que debes hacer es dejar los valores `0` y `1` en los atributos `value` de cada uno.

Adicionalmente, una manera de reducir el código sería:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="BONUS" class="col-md-2 control-label">Bono:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <label class="radio radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="BONUS" value="0" @if(Model.BONUS == 0) {<text>checked="checked"</text>}/>No
        </label>
        <label class="radio radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="BONUS" value="1" @if(Model.BONUS == 1) {<text>checked="checked"</text>}/>Si
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda.